# Prevent Moving to Next Tab If Input Field Is Empty

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiple tabs and input fields within the tabs. When a user clicks the continue button and the input field is blank I want to prevent them from moving to the next tab. I have tried preventDefault(); and return false; and neither seemed to be working for me.

Here is my code, any help with what I am doing wrong is appreciated!

```
$('.btn-next').click(function (event) {
        var businessNameInput = $.trim($('#businessName').val());

        if (businessNameInput === '') {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('Oops, looks like something is missing!');
        } else {
            console.log("Yay, we're good to go!");
        }
    });
```

The console logs work for each option (input blank or not) but it still moves to the next tab.

I am using Fuel UX Wizard for the tabs and Next and previous button. I took a look at their code and pulled this out, I think it is their next button function...

```
var Wizard = function( element, options ) {
            var kids;

            this.$element = $( element );
            this.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.wizard.defaults, options );
            this.options.disablePreviousStep = ( this.$element.attr( 'data-restrict' ) === "previous" ) ? true : this.options.disablePreviousStep;
            this.currentStep = this.options.selectedItem.step;
            this.numSteps = this.$element.find( '.steps li' ).length;
            this.$prevBtn = this.$element.find( 'button.btn-prev' );
            this.$nextBtn = this.$element.find( 'button.btn-next' );

            kids = this.$nextBtn.children().detach();
            this.nextText = $.trim( this.$nextBtn.text() );
            this.$nextBtn.append( kids );

            // handle events
            this.$prevBtn.on( 'click.fu.wizard', $.proxy( this.previous, this ) );
            this.$nextBtn.on( 'click.fu.wizard', $.proxy( this.next, this ) );
            this.$element.on( 'click.fu.wizard', 'li.complete', $.proxy( this.stepclicked, this ) );

            this.selectedItem( this.options.selectedItem );

            if ( this.options.disablePreviousStep ) {
                this.$prevBtn.attr( 'disabled', true );
                this.$element.find( '.steps' ).addClass( 'previous-disabled' );
            }
        };
```

Here is the link to the full JS file from the FuelUX Wizard: www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.0.2/js/fuelux.js

Comment: Have you tried disabling the next button so long as the fields are empty? Instead of letting them click and stopping them, don't let them click in the first place.

Comment: make sure you target the correct id $('#businessName') and you should put event.preventDefault() right after click, not in if statement

Comment: I have tried disabling the next button but feel a prompt when the empty field is present will help people figure out the problem rather than just not letting them continue (personal preference)

Comment: Yes, id is correct as the console log for empty or not runs. I tried moving to top of code but it still wasn't working.

Comment: Pls show the code that selects the next tab. It looks like that the tab is being selected by another event target element.

Comment: @f_martinez I've added the code to my question

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed ready function. Here's a sample code:

```
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
  $('.btn-next').click(function (event) {
  var businessNameInput = $.trim($('#businessName').val());
  if (businessNameInput === '') {
        console.log('Oops, looks like something is missing!');
        return false;
   } else {
  console.log("Yay, we're good to go!");
  return true;
    }
});
});
</script>

 <form action="YourFileName">
 Enter Business Name:<input type="text" id="businessName">
 <input type="submit" class="btn-next">
 </form>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: she already mentioned that console logs work  so the code is working only problem is preventing the default action so I don't think this is going to help

Comment: Ya, thanks for your response but I have the document ready function already in place.

Comment: @Madhuri I edited my question to include the code for the next tab

Answer (score 0):

Use `.stopImmediatePropagation()` instead of `.preventDefault()`:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Follow the official docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

**Big Update:**

Sorry for long silence at first. I've explored you problem in deep and discovered that the *Wizard* has built-in event `actionclicked.fu.wizard` (http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#wizard-usage-events) which allows to intercept step changing with ease.

The handler for that event is the only right place for calling `event.preventDefault` to stop changing step in the Wizard.

I've created simple example where you have to check mandatory checkbox in order to move to the next step: http://jsfiddle.net/go3koktm/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this out and it still didn't prevent the continue function from running.. I have edited my question again and added a link to the full JS file from FuelUx Wizard. Maybe there is something I am missing in there...

Comment: Updated. Hope it's still actual.